# WAMP Server: What am I doing wrong?

Tags: apache-http-server, wamp

I am brand new to web development...and getting WAMPServer running is a barrier no amount of Googling has helped solve.

When I install WAMPServer it works fine. When I try to add local domain names, it goes wrong. Can anyone tell me why?

### Things I have tried.

In

> C:/Windows/System32/drivers/etc/hosts

I added

> '127.0.0.1 my.testsite'

Then, in

> C:/wamp/bin/apache/Apache2.2.22/conf/httpd.conf

I have removed the # from

> '# Include conf/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf'

Then, in C:/wamp/bin/apache/Apache2.2.22/conf/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf I added

> < Directory C:/WAMPprojects> 
> Order Deny,Allow 
> Allow from all 
> < /Directory>

and

> < VirtualHost *:80> 
> DocumentRoot “C:/WAMPprojects/Hermes” 
> ServerName my.testsite  
> < /VirtualHost>

When I enter my.testsite into the address bar, I expect to see the content of the index.html page that’s in the Hermes folder.

After a fresh install of WAMP where the taskbar icon turns green, I Have made these changes and every time I restart WAMP Server it stops at orange.

### Therefore I have also tried:

- Turning off Skype
- Changing Skype settings so it does not listen at port 80 (Tools>Options>Advanced>Connection>Use port 80 and 443 as alternatives for incoming connections. Untick.)
- Checking nothing else is listening at port 80
- Changing the port to 8080
- Changing the port to a different number
- Adding ::1 to hosts

I cannot determine what’s going on in the Apache error log.

I am on Windows XP (SP3) and Apache 2.2.22 Is it a case of incompatibility or can it be fixed?

Thank you very much in advance if anyone can give me a clue on this - I've been stuck for months now.

Comment: The real key here is that when you restart WAMP after modifying your conf files, your status icon isn't going green - this is most likely due to an issue with your configuration files (meaning you wouldn't have needed to futz around with skype, ports, etc) - debug efforts should focus on the conf files.  I'm not sure where the errors with conf files get logged in WAMP, but I'd take the time to figure that out now if I were you . . .

Answer (score 1):

Expanding on my comment:

The real key here is that when you restart Apache after modifying your conf files, your status icon isn't going green - this is most likely due to an issue with your configuration files (meaning you wouldn't have needed to futz around with Skype, ports, etc) - debug efforts should focus on the Apache conf files. I'm not sure where the errors with conf files get logged in WAMP, but I'd take the time to figure that out now if I were you . . .

I think the issue is that `<directory>` sections can't be top level in included conf files.  As stated in [the documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#directory), their [context](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/directive-dict.html#Context) is server config or virtual host, meaning it needs to either be in the main conf file (i.e. *httpd.conf*) or in a `<VirtualHost>` definition.  Try something like this:

```
< VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot “C:/WAMPprojects/Hermes”
    ServerName my.testsite
    <Directory C:/WAMPprojects>
        Order Deny,Allow
        Allow from all
    </Directory>
< /VirtualHost>
```

Comment: No luck unfortunately :/
It bugs me that this _could_ be so simple, but maybe I'll give in and try XAMPP or AMPPS instead.

Comment: what's in your apache error.log?

Comment: Also, switching to one of the other stack distributions probably won't help - you're running into issues with Apache, which is a common thread between all of these . . .

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried adding a **ServerAlias**, like:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "C:/WAMPprojects/Hermes"
    ServerName my.testsite
    ServerAlias my.testsite
    <Directory "C:/WAMPprojects/Hermes">
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

?

Answer (score -1):

Here's some detail on what happens when your brower makes a request to a server that should fill in the details:

- You type http://whatever.invalid in the address bar
- Browser uses system resolver to issue a DNS request to convert whatever.invalid to an IP address
- Browser makes HTTP GET request to the IP returned by that DNS request.
- Within the header of that HTTP GET request, your browser places a "Host:" line, copying the domain name you used, i.e. "Host: whatever.invalid"
- Apache gets the request, IF the IP was correct.
- Apache checks the HTTP header for any "Host:" lines and uses the proper vhost, if such a configuration exists.

So, the piece of the puzzle you are missing is a DNS server willing to take your site name and return the IP on which your Apache server lives, which is currently localhost.

You could run your own local DNS server, or just dispense with vhosts and use `http://localhost` or `http://127.0.0.1` in your browser.

Just reread your question more closely and saw that you used the `hosts` file.  Try pinging `my.testsite` and see if `127.0.0.1` is returned by ping.  You may need to remove any existing `localhost` references in the `hosts` file.  (Incidentally, I just tried a `ping -4 localhost` on the Windows system I'm on and it did cause a ping to `127.0.0.1` ... so it may be something else ...)

Comment: Since they modified their hosts file, the DNS lookup should happen locally.  Of course, if the OP wants to verify that their hosts file is correct, they could just drop to the command prompt, and try pinging `my.testsite`, and see if it resolves.

Comment: Right, I just caught that.